# Assigning admin rights to apps in Linux

Tags: linux

I am using linux mint and have installed Netbeans on it but whenever I run netbeans from accounts other than root it throws an error for not having permission to start glassfish server of netbeans. I also tried running this application using run as administrator option but then the application does not start.

So is there a way to assign netbeans admin rights permanently so that whenever I start this application from other accounts I should not face this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use [xdg-su](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0beta1/xdg-su.html):

> xdg-su provides a graphical dialog that prompts the user for a password to run command as user  or as root if no user was specified.
>
> xdg-su is for use inside a desktop session only.

If your launch command is `/usr/bin/netbeans/`, change it  to `xdg-su -c /usr/bin/netbeans`.

---

Alternatively, find out where netbeans stores its workspace and assign ownership to your current user.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the program you'd like to run as root into the sudoers file. (run the command "visudo" as root)